# how to hotpatch phar package?

Tags: php, checksum, phar, hotpatching

how do you hotpatch a phar package? for example if i want to hotpatch

```php
if (function_exists('posix_getuid') && posix_getuid() === 0) {
if ($commandName !== 'self-update' && $commandName !== 'selfupdate') {
$io->writeError('<warning>Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details</warning>');
```

from composer into

```php
if (false && posix_getuid() === 0) {
if ($commandName !== 'self-update' && $commandName !== 'selfupdate') {
$io->writeError('<warning>Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details</warning>');
```

how should i do that? just editing the code normally results in

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PharException: phar "/usr/local/bin/composer" has a broken signature in /usr/local/bin/composer:28
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/bin/composer(28): Phar::mapPhar()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /usr/local/bin/composer on line 28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first unpack the phar:

```
rm -rfv unpacked;
mkdir unpacked;
php --define open_basedir= --define phar.readonly=0 -r '(new Phar("composer.phar"))->convertToExecutable(Phar::TAR,Phar::NONE)->extractTo("unpacked/");'
```

then do your patching in the unpacked dir, in your case `unpacked/src/Composer/Console/Application.php` , then re-pack the phar:

```
rm -f hotpatched.phar;
php --define open_basedir= --define phar.readonly=0 -r '$phar=new Phar("hotpatched.phar");$phar->buildFromDirectory("unpacked");$phar->setStub("#!/usr/bin/env php\n".$phar->createDefaultStub("bin/composer"));'
```

but replace `bin/composer` with the phar package's real entrypoint (in the case of composer, it's `bin/composer` )
then make the hotpatched phar executable:

```
chmod +x hotpached.phar
```

and voila, your phar is patched :) the phar even works with php.ini `phar.require_hash=1`

tip: you can add `$phar->compress(Phar::BZ2);` if you want the phar compressed/smaller

Answer (score 1):

You can configure php to tell phars to not use the signature check at runtime  that is causing that error.

Configure the following to **false**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.configuration.php#ini.phar.require-hash

> This option will force all opened Phar archives to contain some kind
> of signature (currently MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA512 and OpenSSL are
> supported), and will refuse to process any Phar archive that does not
> contain a signature.

Edit:

1. Download composer source:
   https://github.com/composer/composer
2. Modify Compiler to remove hash
   https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/575fbfb53fcc2388916d554271c99c8281fea782/src/Composer/Compiler.php#L81
3. You will need to recompile composer using the compile command and run with phar.require-hash=0

Comment: nice try, unfortunately the hash when present will still be validated, even with `phar.require_hash=0` im still getting `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PharException: phar "/usr/local/bin/composer" has a broken signature in /usr/local/bin/composer:28`